# AngularJS : Q deferreds and requestFileSystem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

I'm encountering some problems when trying to resolve a deferred in the following situation

```
services.factory('MyService', ['$q',
 function($q) {
  var Foo = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, deferred.resolve, this.errorHandler);
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    Foo: Foo
  }
 }
]);
```

Then inside a controller:

```
var bar = new MyService.Foo().then(function(cb) {
  console.log(cb)
});
```

If I use deferred.resolve outside requestFileSystem function then it works perfectly but in the situation above nothing happens.
PS: the third parameter to requestFileSystem function is a callback which gets a filesystem object once it's ready.

EDIT:
this is bar:

```
Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
```

the fourth parameter to requestFileSystem is a function which logs to console filesystem API initialization errors but in this case it's not called because requestFileSystem is successful so deferred.resolve should be called. if i replace deferred with a normal function:

```
 window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function(filesystem){
   console.log(filesystem);
 }, this.errorHandler);
```

then filesystem object is returned correctly:

```
DOMFileSystem {root: DirectoryEntry, name: "http_127.0.0.1_3000:Temporary"}
```

EDIT2:

I tried to make a simple test by simulating requestFilesystem function with my own function and it works:

```
var Foo = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    asd(deferred.resolve)
    return deferred.promise;
}

function asd(callback) {
    callback('it works')
}

MyService.Foo().then(function(cb){
  console.log(cb)
})
```

Comment: I'm guessing the promise gets returned but it's never resolved? Add some debug statements to see where it hangs.

Comment: What is the fourth parameter? Do you get any errors in the console? And don't use `new`, `Foo` is no constructor.

Comment: Can you point us to the documentation of `requestFileSystem` method?

Comment: doc links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem

http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is how and when `deferred.resolve` is invoked.
Fixed code:

```
services.factory('MyService', ['$q','$rootScope',
 function($q,$rootScope) {
  var Foo = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function(result){
      deferred.resolve(result);
      $rootScope.$apply();//force angular to resolve promise
    }, this.errorHandler);
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    Foo: Foo
  }
 }
]);
```

Thing is, when you invoke 'deferred.resolve' outside of angular lifecycle (callback of filesystem request is outside of angular lifecycle), you have to manually invoke '$rootScope.$apply()' otherwise promise won't be resolved.

Comment: You can pass around the `resolve` function, it is a closure that does not depend on calling on the right deferred object. I've checked it in the source code as that was my first suspicion :-)

Comment: @Bergi oops,my bad, thanks. Just few hours ago I saw invocation like `deferred[fnc].apply(deferred,params)` so I thought it is depended.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better solution from [github.com/maciel310/angular-filesystem](https://github.com/maciel310/angular-filesystem/blob/master/src/filesystem.js)

```
//wrap resolve/reject in an empty $timeout so it happens within the Angular call stack
//easier than .apply() since no scope is needed and doesn't error if already within an apply
function safeResolve(deferral, message) {
    $timeout(function() {
        deferral.resolve(message);
    });
}
function safeReject(deferral, message) {
    $timeout(function() {
        deferral.reject(message);
    });
}
```